# How to place a close button to the top of popup div without having it move around when the screen is resized

Tags: html, css, image, button

I'm looking for some help in placing a 'close' button to the top of a popup div without having it move around when the screen is resized. I've tried setting absolute and relative positions but it doesn't seem to work - it moves around when I resize the window.

Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/R2UHm.

I'm not sure why the jsfiddle isn't showing it exactly the way I want, but I did only clip out that small section.

I attached a link to a screen shot of what I'm looking for. https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4eWu.jpg

```
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the close button inside another div

```
<div class="overlay-bg">
    <div class="close-btn-wrapper">
       <button class="close-btn2">X</button>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay-content">
    // rest of the content
```

Css

```
.close-btn-wrapper{
    position:relative;
    width:700px;
    left:30%;
}

.close-btn2{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Change the `top` and `right` values as u need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It seems to be moving in the right direction but this is the result

http://imgur.com/KsFIhau.jpg

Comment: It shrunk the popup box to only fit the wrapper in the center and not fill the entire screen.

Comment: Ya i see that. How did you position the content section in the overlay

Comment: Yep I have it positioned relative

Comment: I mean the div `.overlay-content`, is this positioned relatively?

Comment: Yep. the .overlay-content has a relative position attribute

Comment: Will you be able to move <button class="close-btn2">X</button> to inside the div overlay-content?

Comment: I can move it to the inside, the only thing is; I wanted it to always be visible. As soon as you scroll down it will disappear right?

Comment: No you move it inside the div and remove this style `.overlay-bg{position:relative;}`, then you should be fine. Change the top and right values accordingly. Try this and let me know.

Comment: Just tried. If I get rid of the relative positioning on the .overlay-bg then it shrinks the box back to the image I showed you before. If I instead put        position:fixed it will fill the screen again.

As for the close button, It dissappears as soon as I scroll down the page.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that you have to use `position:fixed` for `.overlay-bg`. When you do this does it gives the way you want the close button to be?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the positioning of the close button is ok due to the top and right attributes but it still disappears when I scroll down

Comment: Sorry, try what exactly?

Comment: Ok, that works a lot better. It moves SLIGHTLY when the window is resized but I can deal with that.  One final thing, how do I get it to display on top even when the window is resized - what happens is, if I resize the window enough, the close button will move enough to be hidden behind the popup window